# Как на чистом css стилизовать последний нечётный элемент?

Tags: html, css

Есть условный родительский блок с секциями, которые добавляются и удаляются динамически:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  ...
</div>
```

Можно ли на чистом css стилизовать последнюю нечётную секцию? То есть если секций чётное число, тогда ничего не происходит, а если нечётное, то к последней секции применяются другие стили?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать псевдокласс последнего элемента [`:last-child`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child) и с помощью [`:nth-child`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child) выделить все нечётные элементы:

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: black
}
section:last-child:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорош, затащил задачку)

Comment: когда 6 селектов не работает

Comment: @L.Vadim, а ничего, что 6 элемент - это чётный?

Comment: так он должен вроде покрасить в красный пятый, по вопросу, или нет

Comment: @L.Vadim, "То есть если секций чётное число, тогда ничего не происходит, а если нечётное, то к последней секции применяются другие стили"

Comment: а понял, а почему 2n+1 можете обьянисть

Comment: @L.Vadim, 2n - берём два элемента, 2n+1 - берём первый из двух

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку формулировка «последний нечетный» не подразумевает, что он одновременно будет и последним, и нечетным, вот альтернативный вариант, который при любом количестве элементов будет подсвечивать последний нечетный.

```css
section {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #000;
}

section:nth-last-child(-n+2):not(:nth-child(even)) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Он по-моему уточнил: "То есть если секций чётное число, тогда ничего не происходит, а если нечётное, то к последней секции применяются другие стили". Но ваш пример познавателен

Comment: @Yuri да, я видел. Добавил ответ исключительно для базы знаний, если кто-нибудь другой будет делать поиск по вопросу.